# Assemble handlebar template relative to its path

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

So I'm trying to look through a directory and compile all hbs files. But the thing is that the hbs file should compile in the folder it lies in.

pseudo code:

```
assemble: {
            options: {
                flatten: false,
                assets: 'assets',
                dev: true,
                livereloadPort: '<%- livereloadPort %>',
                partials: ['dev/assemble/partials/*.hbs'],
                layout: 'dev/assemble/banner.hbs',
                data: ['dev/assemble/data/*.{json,yml}']
            },

            // ----------------------------------------------------------------
            // assembles

            dev: {
                options: {
                    data: ['dev/assemble/data/*.{json,yml}']
                },
                src: ['dev/banners/**/*.hbs'],
                expand: true,
                dest: '<% SAME AS SRC FILE %>',
                ext: '.html'
            }
        },
```

So basically this folder structure;

/banners/
    /bannerfolder_1/
        handlebarfile.hbs
    /bannerfolder_2/
        another_handlebarfile.hbs

Would result in this;

/banners/
    /bannerfolder_1/
        handlebarfile.hbs
        handlebarfile.**html**
    /bannerfolder_2/
        another_handlebarfile.hbs
        another_handlebarfile.**html**

Can this be done?

Comment: What happens when you run it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following [globbing pattern / dynamic mapping](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

```
files: {
          expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
          cwd: 'dev/',      // Src matches are relative to this path.
          src: ['banners/**/*.hbs'], // Actual pattern(s) to match.
          dest: 'dev/',   // Destination path prefix.
          ext: '.html',   // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
          extDot: 'last'   // Extensions in filenames begin after the last dot
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I might have explained it poorly. This doesn't seem like it would do the trick. I have edited the question for clarification.

Comment: Oh, you want to compile the Handlebars files as static sites? I see, I'll try and edit my answer soon.

Comment: Indeed. Cool. Much appreciated!

Comment: See the edit, the edited dynamic mapping should produce the results you want.